# SImple first order population growth problem can solve for c but dont know how to get K

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The time rate change of a rabbit population $P$ is proportional to the square root of $P$. At $t=0$ the population numbers $100$ rabbits and is increasing by 20 rabbits per month. How many rabbits will there be one year later?

Setup:

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = k\sqrt{p}$$

Solution:

$$\int\frac{dp}{\sqrt{p}} = \int kdt$$

which becomes: $$2\sqrt{p} = tk+c$$

$$P(0)=100$$

Solve for C:

$$2 \sqrt{100}=0k + C$$

$$20 = c$$

So we have:

$$2 \sqrt{P} = tk + 20$$

Where do I proceed from here? Also why can't I take $20$ and multiply it by $12$ and add that to $100?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to find P(t) and be able to use it to find P(12).

From given information we have:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=k\sqrt{P} \tag1$$

The initial condition could be used to determine the value of $k$ as follows:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=20=k\sqrt{100}$$

$$k=2$$

From (1) we could separate the variables and integrate as follows:

$$\int{\frac{dP}{\sqrt{P}}}=\int {2dt}$$

$$2 \sqrt{P}=2t+C$$

$$ P=(\frac{2t+C}{2})^2 \tag 2$$

We are given that P(0)=100, so:

$$P(0)=100=(\frac{C}{2})^2$$

Solving for C, we get $$C=20$$

Using (2), we can now write $$P(t)=(t+10)^2$$

After 12 month from the start, we calculate $P(12)$ to be:

$$P(12)=484$$

Comment: can you explain $$\frac{dp}{dt}=20= k\sqrt{100}$$

Comment: Yes, the problem states that "The population numbers 100 rabbits and is increasing by 20 rabbits per month". So, $dp/dt=20$. This rate of change is the same you found in your question's first equation with $p=100$.